# Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=mypackage/.AlarmReceiver (has extras) }: not found

Tags: android

Here my manifest? Is a manifest problem? Many many hours spent to discover the problem... is a service that starts a class by intent (using alarmmanager). If no a manifest problem, what's the problem?

Thanks for help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mypackage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="CrashReports">

        <service android:name="UnUsedService">
        <intent-filter>
        <action
        android:name="org.gortcloud.startatboot.UnUsedService" />
        </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver android:name="AutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
        <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mypackage.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".SobService"/>

        <activity android:name="Index"></activity>
        <activity android:name="SendText"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

logcat

```
    E/ThrottleService(  149): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
D/dalvikvm(  149): GC_CONCURRENT freed 637K, 13% free 8307K/9479K, paused 25ms+12ms, total 142ms
D/AndroidRuntime(14611): 
D/AndroidRuntime(14611): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(14611): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm(14611): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(14611): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(14611): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(14611): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/AndroidRuntime(14611): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
W/ActivityManager(  149): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MainActivity.apk
D/dalvikvm( 2860): GC_CONCURRENT freed 457K, 14% free 5292K/6087K, paused 17ms+4ms, total 75ms
W/ActivityManager(  149): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/MainActivity.apk
D/dalvikvm(  149): GC_CONCURRENT freed 614K, 12% free 8360K/9479K, paused 22ms+30ms, total 125ms
D/dalvikvm(  149): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 282K, 13% free 8265K/9479K, paused 69ms, total 70ms
D/dalvikvm(  149): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 234K, 13% free 8267K/9479K, paused 86ms, total 87ms
D/dalvikvm(  149): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 239K, 13% free 8270K/9479K, paused 68ms, total 68ms
I/PackageManager(  149): Removing non-system package:org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza
I/ActivityManager(  149): Force stopping package org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza uid=10044
I/ActivityManager(  149): Killing proc 10610:org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/u0a44: force stop
W/ActivityManager(  149): Force removing ActivityRecord{411fe0f0 org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/.MainActivity}: app died, no saved state
W/InputDispatcher(  149): channel '412b50c0 org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher(  149): channel '412b50c0 org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/WindowState(  149): WIN DEATH: Window{412b50c0 org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza.MainActivity paused=false}
W/InputDispatcher(  149): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '412b50c0 org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza.MainActivity (server)'
I/Choreographer(  149): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/WindowManager(  149): WINDOW DIED Window{412b50c0 org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza.MainActivity paused=false}
I/Choreographer(  258): Skipped 238 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/PackageManager(  149): Package org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza codePath changed from /data/app/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza-2.apk to /data/app/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
W/InputMethodManagerService(  149): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 10610 uid 10044
I/PackageManager(  149): Running dexopt on: org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza
D/dalvikvm(14630): DexOpt: load 129ms, verify+opt 643ms, 962252 bytes
W/PackageManager(  149): Code path for pkg : org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza changing from /data/app/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza-2.apk to /data/app/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza-1.apk
W/PackageManager(  149): Resource path for pkg : org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza changing from /data/app/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza-2.apk to /data/app/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza-1.apk
D/dalvikvm(  149): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 320K, 13% free 8281K/9479K, paused 72ms, total 73ms
I/ActivityManager(  149): Force stopping package org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza uid=10044
D/PackageManager(  149): New package installed in /data/app/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza-1.apk
W/PackageManager(  149): Not granting permission android.permission.READ_LOGS to package org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza (protectionLevel=50 flags=0x8be46)
I/ActivityManager(  149): Force stopping package org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza uid=10044
D/dalvikvm(  204): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm(  258): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1ms
D/dalvikvm(  204): GC_EXPLICIT freed 216K, 62% free 5881K/15367K, paused 8ms+19ms, total 155ms
D/dalvikvm(  258): GC_EXPLICIT freed 409K, 39% free 7423K/12103K, paused 8ms+22ms, total 156ms
D/dalvikvm(  323): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm(  323): GC_EXPLICIT freed 177K, 10% free 5564K/6151K, paused 8ms+9ms, total 88ms
I/InputReader(  149): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
D/PackageManager(  149): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
D/PackageManager(  149): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
D/BackupManagerService(  149): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
D/dalvikvm(  149): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
I/AccountTypeManager(  367): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 53ms(wall) 5ms(cpu)
D/dalvikvm(  149): GC_EXPLICIT freed 503K, 15% free 8140K/9479K, paused 65ms+21ms, total 204ms
I/InputReader(  149): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
D/PackageManager(  149): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged
D/PackageManager(  149): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged
D/BackupManagerService(  149): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza flg=0x8000010 (has extras) }
V/BackupManagerService(  149): removePackageParticipantsLocked: uid=10044 #1
V/BackupManagerService(  149): addPackageParticipantsLocked: #1
W/InputMethodManagerService(  149): Found no subtypes in a system IME: com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
I/AccountTypeManager(  367): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 11ms(wall) 7ms(cpu)
I/Choreographer(  258): Skipped 533 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm(  149): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
D/dalvikvm(  367): GC_CONCURRENT freed 403K, 12% free 5471K/6215K, paused 100ms+14ms, total 174ms
W/RecognitionManagerService(  149): no available voice recognition services found
D/dalvikvm(  149): GC_EXPLICIT freed 400K, 14% free 8170K/9479K, paused 27ms+47ms, total 266ms
D/AndroidRuntime(14611): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(14611): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 458K/2048K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 13ms
D/jdwp    (14611): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
D/dalvikvm(14611): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(14611): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
D/AndroidRuntime(14647): 
D/AndroidRuntime(14647): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(14647): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm(14647): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(14647): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(14647): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm(14647): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/AndroidRuntime(14647): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
I/ActivityManager(  149): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 14647
W/WindowManager(  149): Failure taking screenshot for (123x221) to layer 21025
D/AndroidRuntime(14647): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(14647): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 77% free 489K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 11ms
D/jdwp    (14647): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
D/dalvikvm(14647): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
I/AndroidRuntime(14647): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
D/dalvikvm(  258): GC_CONCURRENT freed 539K, 38% free 7520K/12103K, paused 16ms+127ms, total 360ms
D/dalvikvm(14658): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/ActivityManager(  149): Start proc org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza for activity org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/.MainActivity: pid=14658 uid=10044 gids={3003, 1028}
E/Trace   (14658): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
I/Choreographer(  149): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/ACRA    (14658): ACRA is enabled for org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza, intializing...
D/ACRA    (14658): Using default Report Fields
D/ACRA    (14658): Looking for error files in /data/data/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/files
D/dalvikvm(14658): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 179K, 9% free 5372K/5895K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(14658): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.965MB for 457616-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(14658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 9% free 5817K/6343K, paused 19ms+13ms, total 61ms
D/dalvikvm(14658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 48K, 6% free 6322K/6663K, paused 15ms+4ms, total 65ms
D/dalvikvm(14658): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 18ms
D/dalvikvm(14658): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 48K, 6% free 6464K/6855K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(14658): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.234MB for 668816-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(14658): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 7117K/7559K, paused 58ms, total 58ms
D/dalvikvm(14658): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 7117K/7559K, paused 16ms+4ms, total 64ms
I/Choreographer(14658): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(14658): Skipped 233 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/gralloc_goldfish(14658): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
I/ActivityManager(  149): Displayed org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/.MainActivity: +1s713ms
I/Choreographer(  149): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  149): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(14658): Skipped 271 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm(  243): GC_CONCURRENT freed 384K, 13% free 5798K/6599K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 36ms
I/Choreographer(14658): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  149): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/dalvikvm(14692): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/ActivityManager(  149): Start proc org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza:remote for broadcast org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/.AlarmReceiver: pid=14692 uid=10044 gids={3003, 1028}
E/Trace   (14692): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
D/ACRA    (14692): ACRA is enabled for org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza, intializing...
D/ACRA    (14692): Using default Report Fields
D/ACRA    (14692): Looking for error files in /data/data/org.gortcloud.perledisaggezza/files
D/gralloc_goldfish(14692): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

UnUsedService (starts from my activity by:

```
startService(new Intent(this, UnUsedService.class));
```

UnUsedService

```
public class UnUsedService extends Service {

//private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//startService(new Intent(this, UnUsedService.class));
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

//  super.onStart();
super.onStart(intent, startId);

Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)     getApplicationContext().getSystemService  (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     AlarmReceiver.class),      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()+1000,     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

}};
```

Receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
 }
```

Comment: Post all of your LogCat errors and the relevant Java code, so we can see more of what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that you're creating the wrong type of PendingIntent:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(UnUsedService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

You want to target your BroadcastReceiver, so you need to use:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmReceiver.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

Comment: You are still calling `PendingIntent.getService()` not `getBroadcast()` and did you post all of the LogCat errors?

Comment: I get a compile time error `No enclosing instance of the type OnAlarmReceiver is accessible in `on `AlarmReceiver.this`.

Answer (score -1):

instead of this in your mainifest. .

try this

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.mypackage.Index"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.mypackage.SendText"></activity>
```